# То, чего не следует бояться

Tags: лексика

Какое слово может определить событие, поступок как нисколько не волнительный, нетревожный, совершаемый с чувством спокойствия и самообладания? Например, когда речь идет о поединке, который не держит бойца в страхе. "Бесстрашный" обозначает самого бойца, а какое прилагательное обозначит поединок, который "таков, что не вызывает в бойце чувства страха"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> А если взять бытовую ситуацию, даже, например, подход к девушке. Вот
>   он вдруг перестал быть волнительным. Безопасное знакомство?

Бесстрастное знакомство. Не задевающее чувств.

Синонимы *того, чего не следует бояться:*

*хладнокровный, флегматичный, уравновешенный, невозмутимый, холодный, прохладный, равнодушный.*

Answer (score 1):

Как правило, в большинстве случаев, мы боимся того, чего не знаем, либо того, что должно произойти в первый раз. Например, смерть страшна хотя бы тем, что умираем только раз, и понять, как это будет происходить, не представляется возможным. Обычные и привычные нам дела, страха как такового не вызывают.

Таким образом, можно выделить два качества, по которым можно будет предположить, насколько то или иное действие или явление будет для человека восприниматься с чувством страха, а именно это: 1) известность и 2) повторяемость.

Исходя из этих качеств можно выбирать любое подходящее для нужного вам изложения слово:

- привычный;
- обычный;
- обыденный;
- известный;
- приевшийся;
- наскучивший;
- надоевший;
- скучный.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, ***безопасный*** поединок?

***Обновление:***

Александр предложил *безрисковый поединок,* я сказал, что не согласен, но в итоге понял, что и мой вариант не лучше. По размышлении пришёл к выводу, что, по-моему, одним словом это не назовёшь, и так же, как со знакомством, сказал бы ***не пугающий бойца*** поединок.

Comment: А если взять бытовую ситуацию, даже, например, подход к девушке. Вот он вдруг перестал быть волнительным. Безопасное знакомство?

Comment: Ну нет, тогда можно сказать "не пугающее знакомство".

Comment: _Малообязывающее_ знакомство, _безрисковый_ поединок?

Comment: @Alex_ander: безрисковый поединок? Не сказал бы. Боец может не боятся поединка, выходить на него "с чувством спокойствия и самообладания", но это не обязательно значит, что он не рискует. Хотя прихожу в таком случае к тому, что и мой вариант *безопасный* так же тогда не годится.

Comment: Это субъективное восприятие рисков (его собственное и оценка соотношения сил со стороны). Безопасность - объективная оценка, в абсолютном смысле она возможна напр. при дуэли холостыми патронами.